# Window focus for 2nd X11 window

Tags: xorg, mobaxterm

I have a linux command line application that I access via an SSH client and that opens plot windows via a detached system call and X11 forwarding.
An minimal example would be to run the command `glxgears &`, e.g. via a python system call (or simply in the terminal)

When I open the first plot, the (keyboard) focus shifts from the terminal window to the plot window. This is the desired behaviour.

When I open a second plot/window without closing the first, the behaviour depends on which SSH client I use:

- mobaXterm (V22), putty: the focus remains with the terminal window
- reflectionX (V14): the focus shifts to the plot window (desired behaviour)

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour also with mobaXterm or putty?